# dhcp and dns client services not starting in XP

Tags: windows-xp, service

The error I get when I try to start them via Codestuff Starter is "1068" - could not start the depending service".

I know that these services have no dependencies...

I guess something is wrong with the registry after hard reset.

Is there a way to fix this without reinstalling the system?

Please help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

restart required
http://windowsxp.mvps.org/dhcp.htm

Comment: This helped, you're right!